# Analogue ignoreElements() in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on the task of rewriting classes from RxJava to Coroutines and ran into the problem of finding an analogue of the `ignoreElements()` operator. What can replace it in case of using Coroutines?

For example, in this case. I replace `Completable` with `Flow<Unit>`:

```
    private fun observeHistory(): Completable =
        sensorDataService.observeRangeData()
            .doOnNext {
                historyRepo.add(
                    HistoryData(...)
                )
            }
            .ignoreElements()
```

And got this

````
    private fun observeHistory(): Flow<Unit> = flow {
        sensorDataService.observeRangeData()
            .onEach {
                historyRepo.add(
                    HistoryData(...)
                )
            }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Maybe just `flow.filter { false }`?

Comment: Could you please give examples on how you would actually use it in your coroutines code if you had it? Because `filter { false }` does work, but I really wonder where you would actually need this.

Comment: @Joffrey i'm added one of my finctions as sample in question

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what RxJava code you are migrating. The RxJava `ignoreElements()` operator return [`Completable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Completable.html) and suppresses all of the items emitted, in other words, it emits nothing.

So, if you have something like this in RxJava:

```
fun saveData(): Completable {
    return yourObservable
         .doOnComplete {
            // save data
         }
         .ignoreElements()
}
```

then in Kotlin Coroutines you can use just suspend method without a return value:

```
suspend fun saveData(data: String) {
    // save data
}
```

but if you want to keep a reactive approach you can convert it to Kotlin Flow but with Flow, you don't have an alternative to emit nothing, feel free to return your source type (you can return Unit type but it looks pointless then maybe you should reconsider why you use Flow here):

```
 fun saveData(data: String): Flow<String> {
       return yourFlow
           .onCompletion {
               // save data
           }
    }
```

and then you can just ignore the value during collecting:

```
saveData(data)
  .collect()
```

Comment: *with Kotlin Flow you don't have an alternative to emit nothing* - that's not quite true, @Tenfour04 actually suggested `filter { false }` which does exactly that

Comment: replied under your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497690/analogue-ignoreelements-in-coroutines/73499487#comment129794519_73499487

Answer (score -1):

Technically one equivalent of `observable.ignoreElements()` would be `flow.filter { false }`: it returns a flow with 0 elements (skipping all elements of the source flow), and completes when the source flow completes. That said, the resulting `Flow<T>` would not be an ideal representation of what you're actually returning.

A better return type to express this would be `Deferred<Unit>`, which better matches Rx's `Completable`, for instance with `someScope.async(LAZY) { flow.collect() }` - but that would be even less idiomatic.

A more idiomatic approach to solve the problem in your example is to use a suspend function instead, because this is what best represents a single async value (but in a sequential way thanks to coroutines):

```kotlin
private suspend fun observeHistory() {
    sensorDataService.observeRangeData().collect {
        historyRepo.add(HistoryData(...))
    }
}
```

Then if you want to launch this as a background process from the calling code, you can use `launch { observeHistory() }` in a proper coroutine scope, which you would need anyway if you had returned a flow (because collecting the flow is suspending too).

Comment: `filter { false }` doesn't look like an alternative anyway, it's a dirty workaround if you need to do something at the end then you can do it in the `.onCompletion` operator

Comment: @sergpetrov it is indeed a bit of a stretch to say it's an exact equivalent given the return type. I edited to make it clearer that it's just one equivalent, as we could also return a `Deferred<Unit>` to better match `Completable`. In any case, the point is rather to direct the user towards using a `suspend` function here, which would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Yes, I also mentioned using `suspend` function in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but you're not using it the same way. You're including an action done after the completion as part of the suspend function, which is not equivalent to what OP is doing, nor a plain `ignoreElements()`. The point is to use the suspension to wait for completion, not necessarily to perform the action, as that would be done by the calling code in the OP's case (if anything really needs to be done, which is not specified)

Comment: Your suggestion with the call `collect()` operator inside `suspend` function isn't quite good too if we are comparing it with RxJava `Completable` version. Because you lose control of the reactive chain after wrapping it in the function.

Comment: Just to be clear, the suspending approach is more idiomatic, but the usage has to be different for the code to be overall equivalent. The switch is about going from a cold/reactive approach (where the asynchronism is visible in code) to a suspending approach (where it looks sequential in code, even though it is async). After calling this suspend function, one can simply do the stuff that needs to be done. This is the model used by coroutines for single events (outside of flows). This is what replaces single-shot callbacks for instance, and is usually preferred over future-like return types

Comment: If you really wanted to mirror Completable, you could instead return a suspending function.  Deferred is like a Completable, but it can only complete once.  A cold Completable could be called many times to do the action multiple times.